# What is socket, core, threads, CPU?

Tags: cluster-computing, cpu, cpu-cores

I am currently volunteering to learn about linux servers and also I am interested in learning about cluster computing techniques.

In this lab, they have a small cluster with one head node and two compute nodes.

[When I tried the lscpu command on head node, compute node1,node2. Click the link to view the details.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cRQFz.png)

CPUs              - 24 in head, computenode1 and computenode2. **Is it referring to 24 physical CPUs in the motherboard?**

Sockets           - 2 in head, computenode1 and computenode2.**Can anyone explain it?**

Cores per socket  - 6 in head, computenode1 and computenode2.**Can anyone explain it?**

Threads per core  - 2 in head, computenode1 and computenode2.**Can anyone explain it?**

Comment: If you really want to learn, drop using any other OS and just stick to Linux. You will learn quicker. Good luck.

Comment: Related: [Is having multiple cores in a CPU for running multiple threads/processes at once, or for instruction-level parallelism?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/67463541) re: "core" vs. "cpu" as synonyms or not.

Comment: Refer to: https://forum.huawei.com/enterprise/en/what-is-socket-core-threads-cpu/thread/624899-895 What is socket, core, threads, CPU?

Answer (score 69):

A socket is the physical socket where the physical CPU capsules are placed. A normal PC only have one socket.

Cores are the number of CPU-cores per CPU capsule. A modern standard CPU for a standard PC usually have two or four cores.

And some CPUs can run more than one parallel thread per CPU-core. Intel (the most common CPU manufacturer for standard PCs) have either one or two threads per core depending on CPU model.

If you multiply the number of socket, cores and threads, i.e. 2*6*2, then you get the number of "CPUs": 24. These aren't *real* CPUs, but the number of possible parallel threads of execution your system can do.

Just the fact that you have 6 cores is a sign you have a high-end workstation or server computer. The fact that you have two sockets makes it a *very* high-end computer. Usually not even high-end workstations have that these days, only servers.

Comment: Sockets - 2 in head, computenode1 and computenode2. (Each of the nodes have 2 physical socket in them)

Comment: from this "less /proc/cpuinfo", I could see the model name for all the 3 nodes (model name      : Intel(R) Xeon(R) CPU           X5650  @ 2.67GHz). So this server has two physical sockets. Each socket has a CPU. Each CPU has 6 cores in them. Each cores has two threads in them

Comment: I tried this command "less /proc/cpuinfo"[1]. I have just took screenshot of processor 0 and processor 23 (total 24).  What is sibling? what does the cpu cores : 6 refers to? Thanks in advance


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/59MQ0.png

Comment: Example: typical terminology is 6c12t, which means 6 *physical* cores, 12 total *logical* cores (aka hardware threads).  Thus 2 logical per physical, i.e. 2-way [SMT](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simultaneous_multithreading) (such as Intel's HyperThreading).  That can be applied to a whole system, or to a "package" (a physical thing which goes into one socket).  i.e. you could have two 8c16t Xeons in a system for a total of 16c32t.  You would usually *not* apply this across a cluster, since that implies separate systems, not one huge one with coherent shared memory that can run many threads.

Comment: Where can I check the thread count please?